# Multiple VHDL component instantiation

Tags: components, vhdl, instantiation

Following general question:

How do I setup following System (Main) with three submodules (SubX, SubY, SubZ):

```
Main
  |______ SubX
  |         |_______SubZ
  |
  |______ SubZ
```

Here the code:

```
entity System is
    port (
        clk_clk                                : in  std_logic;     
        pwm    : OUT std_logic 
    );
end entity System_Misc;

architecture rtl of System is
    component SubX
        port(clk       : IN  STD_LOGIC;
             pwmSubX   : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    end component SubX;

    component SubZ
        port(clk       : IN  STD_LOGIC;
             pwmSubZ   : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    end component SubZ;


begin
    component SubX
        port map(
            clk      => clk_clk,
            pwmSubX  => pwm
        );

    component SubZ
        port map(
            clk      => clk_clk,
            pwmSubZ  => pwm
        );


end architecture rtl;
```

Is this approach correct because **SubZ** is instantiated in *Main* as well as in **SubX** (not showed here). If I do so, I get an error that I can not connect *pwmSubX* and *pwmSubZ* to the same output **pwm** (Main). 
What is the correct way to solve this issue and/or how would you implement it?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when you connect two different outputs to the same `pwm` port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple drivers for the port `pwm`.

You need to use different signals for each component and the specify how the outputs from `SubX` and `SubZ` will generate the `pwm` output.

Makes no difference where/if `SubX` or `SubZ` were instantiated somewhere else.

```
architecture rtl of System is
    component SubX
        port(clk       : IN  STD_LOGIC;
             pwmSubX   : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    end component SubX;

    component SubZ
        port(clk       : IN  STD_LOGIC;
             pwmSubZ   : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    end component SubZ;


    signal pwmSubX : std_logic;
    signal pwmSubZ : std_logic;


begin
    component SubX
        port map(
            clk      => clk_clk,
            pwmSubX  => pwmSubX
        );

    component SubZ
        port map(
            clk      => clk_clk,
            pwmSubZ  => pwmSubZ
        );

    -- Do what you need with both pwmSubX and pwmSubZ in order to assign
    -- the pwm port
    pwm <= pwmSubX or pwmSubZ;


end architecture rtl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Every component instantiation is elaborated into two nested block statements and zero or more process statements and further block statements.

Each process has a driver for every signal assigned within that process;

Type std_logic is  a resolved std_ulogic. Resolution means that one or more driver values are resolved into an effective value for a signal.

Fleshing out (and correcting) your example:

```
library ieee;                           -- added subx entity/architecture
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity subx is
    port (
        clk:        in  std_logic;
        pwmsubx:    out std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of subx is
    signal pwm:     std_logic;
    component subz is
        port (
            clk:        in  std_logic;
            pwmsubz:    out std_logic
        );
    end component;
    signal pwmsubz: std_logic;

begin
SUB_Z:
    subz 
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            pwmsubz => pwmsubz
        );
    pwm <= pwmsubz after 2 us; 
    pwmsubx <= pwm;   
end architecture;

library ieee;                             -- added subz entity/architecture
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity subz is
    port (
        clk:        in  std_logic;
        pwmsubz:    out std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of subz is
    signal pwm:     std_logic;
begin
    pwm <= clk after 1 us;
    pwmsubz <= pwm;
end architecture;

library ieee;                -- added context clause
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity system is
    port (
        clk_clk:         in  std_logic;     
        pwm:             out std_logic 
    );
end entity; --  system_misc;

architecture rtl of system is
    component subx
        port(clk:        in  std_logic;
             pwmsubx:    out std_logic -- ;
        );             -- added
    end component subx;

    component subz
        port(clk:        in  std_logic;
             pwmsubz:    out std_logic -- ;
        );              -- added
    end component subz;

begin

U0:  -- added label
    component subx
        port map (
            clk      => clk_clk,
            pwmsubx  => pwm
        );
U1:   -- added label
    component subz
        port map (
            clk      => clk_clk,
            pwmsubz  => pwm
        );

end architecture rtl;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity system_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of system_tb is
    signal clk:     std_logic := '0';
    signal pwm:     std_logic;
begin
DUT:
    entity work.system
    port map (
        clk_clk => clk,
        pwm => pwm
    );
STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        wait for 3 us;
        clk <= not clk;
        if now > 15 us then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Notice the two components subx and subz have internal signals before being assigned to their outputs which are associated with pwm in system.

This gives us something we can see on a waveform to demonstrate the effects of resolution:

[image: system_tb_showing_X.png]

Where the two drivers are in conflict we get 'X' (red).

Synthesis software generally takes a dim view of shorting two drivers together, not usually allowing wire OR or wire AND internally. Any error you get is likely from your synthesis tool and not a VHDL complaint (you can see it simulates just fine).

How to fix the issues of two drivers for the same signal depends on the meaning of the signal, and that isn't apparent from your example. As André Souto notes you can gate the two outputs together with a logic device.